# How to mapping primary key is VARCHAR2 type and excute my method to generate it

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

I'm grails newbie.i want to mapping primary key with VARCHAR2 and generate primary key using my method to generated its.how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In GORM you can specify your own [function generating ids](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.4%20Custom%20Database%20Identity).

To specify column type take a look into [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.1%20Table%20and%20Column%20Names). For using VARCHAR2 in Oracle DB just [set your property as String](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes).